# Espaços entre Inputs no Twiter Bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Nos formulários de cadastros o espaçamento tanto horizontal como vertical ficam muito grandes, resolvi o problema acrescentando o **style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:-10px"** em cada input, porém, no tamanho sm e xm das colunas ele perde a marge direta com essa solução.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group form-float" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:-10px">
            <div class="form-line">
                <label style="margin-bottom:-5px;">CNPJ*</label>
                <input id="in_cpf_cnpj" name="cpf_cnpj" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group form-float" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:0px">
            <div class="form-line">
                <label style="margin-bottom:-5px">Inscrição estadual*</label>
                <input id="in_rg_insc_estadual" name="rg_insc_estadual" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Também achei isso com cara de gambiarra. Tem como deixar padrão para todos os inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adiciona o seguinte em uma folha de css personalizada:

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

Aconselho usar em uma folha css personalizada e não na padrão do bootstrap. Pq caso vc atualize a versão do bootstrap, vc n vai perder as atualizações.

Comment: valeu@Eduardo, funcionou  blz.